# C# how to automatically call a void or create an object when making a new class

Tags: c#

In my test scenario, I basically have two classes Program.CS and SeleniumLibrary.cs

In program.cs I want to make a new class of SeleniumLibrary.cs, but what I want to accomplish is when I do new() I want to make a new instance of my ieDriver automatically.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //make SeleniumLibrary._iedriver here somehow
        SeleniumLibrary.SeleniumLibrary sl = new SeleniumLibrary.SeleniumLibrary();
        sl.Navigate("www.google.com");
        sl.Navigate("www.nfl.com");
    }
}

class SeleniumLibrary
{
    private InternetExplorerDriver _ieDriver { get; set; }
    private InternetExplorerDriver ieDriver
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ieDriver == null)
                _ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

            return _ieDriver;

        }
    }

    public void Navigate(string url)
    {
        ieDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }
}
```

you can see inside of my navigate method I call ieDriver, but is there a way of cleaning up the code above?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The existing code uses "Lazy Initialization" to create the InternetExplorerDriver automatically the first time it is needed. Why would you want to create one before you need one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an c-tor and inside it create the  ieDrive

Comment: I'm not sure a constructor is true in this case because you'll want to maintain the same object throughout the whole class

Comment: You can make it static

Comment: why make a new?

Answer (score 7):

I must be misunderstanding something here because whats wrong with:

```
class SeleniumLibrary
{     
    private readonly InternetExplorerDriver _ieDriver;

    public SeleniumLibrary() //Constructor
    {
        _ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }    

    public void Navigate(string url)
    {
        _ieDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }
}
```

This is what DUD is proposing in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655682/767890), I'm just spelling it out.

Comment: See i tried but but it doesn't compile Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'ieDriver' does not exist in the current context SeleniumDLL C:\Users\phyrephyre\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\JudgmentEngine\SeleniumDLL\SeleniumDLL\SeleniumLibrary.cs 28 Active

Comment: I tried  public SeleniumDriver() //Constructor
    {
        _ieDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    } 
and it's telling me Method must have a return type

Comment: @JL1 woops, that was a mistake. The constructor is `SeleniumLibrary`, not `SeleniumDriver`. In C# constructors must be named like the class. Edited code. Concerning your first error, the field is `_ieDriver`, not `ieDriver`.